# uninformative error using boost::iterator_adaptor

Tags: c++, generics, boost, iterator, iostream

I am trying to wrap a `istream` with `boost`'s `progress_display` using `boost::iterator_adaptor`. What I have written is

```
class ifstreamWithProgress: public boost::iterator_adaptor <
  ifstreamWithProgress,
  char*,
  boost::use_default,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag > {
public:
//  ifstreamWithProgress(const char* fname_) {}
  ifstreamWithProgress(): iter(std::istream_iterator<char>()), pd(0)
  {}

  ifstreamWithProgress(const std::string& fname_): fname(fname_), fsize(0), pd(fsize) {
    std::ifstream file(fname.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    fsize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fsize = file.tellg() -  fsize;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    iter = std::istream_iterator<char>(file);
    pd.restart(fsize);
  }

  ~ifstreamWithProgress() {
    while( ++pd < fsize);
  }

  const std::istream_iterator<char> getRawIstream() const {
    return iter;
  }

private:
  std::string fname;
  friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
  std::istream_iterator<char> iter;
  std::streampos fsize;
  progress_display pd;

  void increments() {
    iter++;
    ++pd;
  }

  bool equal(const ifstreamWithProgress& rhs) const {
    return this->iter == rhs.getRawIstream();
  }
};
```

This compiles. However when I started to do something like

```
  ifstreamWithProgress is("data.txt");
  ifstreamWithProgress eos;
  is != eos;
```

I get a compile time error saying that it is not copyable. This makes some sense because the display class is derived from `boost::noncopyable`. However what I do not get is where the copying occurs. Any pointers?

PS: the error message is

```
1>c:\users\leon.sit\documents\myprojects\c++\general_models\phoenixdsm\phx\fileProgressBarWrapper.hpp(58) : error C2248: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
1>        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost/noncopyable.hpp(27) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable'
1>        C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost/noncopyable.hpp(22) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
1>        This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ifstreamWithProgress::ifstreamWithProgress(const ifstreamWithProgress &)'
```

which does not point to anywhere in source. However it compiles after commenting the comparison line.

Comment: Since the devil is in the details with compiler errors, you should post the exact code that produces the error (not just 'something like') along with the exact error message. Ideally, both should be copy-n-pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Copying doesn't have to occur anywhere to produce this error. It is a simple reflection of the fact that the compiler must generate a copy constructor. But to do it, it has to copy `progress_display` as well, which is impossible, since the copy constructor of the latter is private.

You can work around by declaring a pointer to the `progress_display` member and defining your own copy constructor and = operator. For example:

```
class ifstreamWithProgress: public boost::iterator_adaptor <
  ifstreamWithProgress,
  char*,
  boost::use_default,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag > {
public:
  ifstreamWithProgress() : pd(0) {
    pd = new progress_display(...);
  }

  ifstreamWithProgress::ifstreamWithProgress(const ifstreamWithProgress &r) : pd(0) {
    pd = new progress_display(...);
  }

  ~ifstreamWithProgress() {
    if (0 != pd) {
      delete pd;
    }
  }

  ifstreamWithProgress& operator= (const ifstreamWithProgress &r) {
    if (0 != pd) {
      delete pd;
    }
    pd = new progress_display(...);
    return *this;
  }

private:
  progress_display *pd;
};
```

Or you can use `shared_ptr<progress_display>`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are intended to be lightweight objects that can be copied. All the standard utilities that accept iterators get them as by value parameters. The inequality `operator !=` defined by `boost_adaptor` is not an exception. Hence this:

```
is != eos;
```

Matches:

```
bool operator != (ifstreamWithProgress, ifstreamWithProgress);
```

(or one of the equivalents). This calls the copy constructor of your `ifstreamWithProgress`, which in turn can't be generated because one of your members is not copyable.